Yup textfield with validation
I have a textfield that accepts hyphens and numbers with min 10 and max 20. On blur out, textfield should show error message if min and max doesn't meet. But, it is taking hyphen also as value. How to show error message based on only numbers entered.
Also, how to show prepropulate textfield with 91- in MUI and value should not go away on typing.
let schema = yup.object({
            accountNumber: yup.string().when([], {
                is: () => accountNumber,
                then: yup
                    .string()
                    .required('Please enter account number')
                    .matches(/^\d+(-\d+)?$/,'Please enter a valid number')
                    .min(10, 'Account number should be between 10 and 20')
                    .max(20, 'Account number should be between 10 and 20'),
                otherwise: yup.string().notRequired(),
            }),
        });

<TextField
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    margin="normal"
                                    fullWidth
                                    value={values.accountNumber}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                                    error={
                                        touched.accountNumber &&
                                        Boolean(errors.accountNumber)
                                    }
                                />


You can use a function that removes all the hyphens, then add the function to onchange of the <TextField/> such that yup gets cleaned input without hyphens
function clearHyphens(number){
     return number.replace(/[-\s]/g, "");
}

Then add it to your handleChange function
To pre-populate 91- just, add a div on the left of your input. Then style it such that it looks like an input.
